# How to display data from parent model using foreign key django

Tags: python, django

I want to display the child model data with the parent model data as well in a queryset.

This is my models in model.py

```
class Shareholders(models.Model):
    sharehold_IC = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{12,12}$'), only_int], max_length=12)
    sharehold_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    sharehold_email = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, unique=True)
    sharehold_address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sharehold_name

class Meeting(models.Model):

    MEETING_STATUS = (
        ('Coming Soon', 'Coming Soon'),
        ('Live', 'Live'),
        ('Closed', 'Closed')

    )
    meeting_ID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=6, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{6,6}$')])
    meeting_title = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    meeting_date = models.DateField()
    meeting_time = models.TimeField()
    meeting_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    meeting_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=MEETING_STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
    


    def __str__(self):
        return self.meeting_ID


class Question(models.Model):
    question_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    meeting_id = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=CASCADE)
    shareholder_IC = models.ForeignKey(Shareholders_Meeting, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='shareholder_ic')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.meeting_id)
```

I try to display all the data from the **Question** model with the shareholders details such as **sharehold_name** from the **Shareholders** model.
This is how I try to do in **Views.py**.

**Views.py**

```
def getMessages(response, meeting_id):
    meeting = Meeting.objects.get(meeting_ID=meeting_id)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(meeting_id=meeting.meeting_ID)
    # print(list(questions.values('shareholder_IC_id')))
    for i in questions:
        print(i.shareholder_ic.all())
    
    return JsonResponse({"questions":list(questions.values())})
```

But somehow I got this error `AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'shareholder_ic'`.
I want to get the result like this:

```
{'question_ID': 141, 'question': "I'm good. How are you?", 'meeting_id_id': '731404', 'shareholder_IC_id': '122311221231', 'date_created': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 7, 3, 40, 12, 160029, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'sharehold_name':'John Steve', 'sharehold_email':'john@gmail.com'}
```

How do I fix this or is there any other way to display the data?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is Question_Meeting in your view?

Comment: Sorry, supposed to be ```Question.objects.filter(meeting_id=meeting.meeting_ID)```

Comment: Don't use **"_id"** at the end of the field name for **ForeignKey**. Behind the scenes, Django appends **"_id"** to the field name to create its database column name, see [**Django ForeignKey**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

Comment: I got this error says ```AttributeError: 'Shareholders' object has no attribute 'all'```

Comment: @Lord-shiv, _Field names should be all lowercase, using underscores instead of camelCase_. You have a typo here: **print(i.shareholder_ic.all())** instead **print(i.shareholder_IC)**

Comment: @Lord-shiv, **`.all()`** method of `QuerySet`. ForeignKey is  a many-to-one relationship - [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, you're not using the `related_name` attribute in your `Question` model correctly. It's not to use an alternative name to refer to the related model, the opposite, it's the name you want to use to refer to the `Question` model from the related model, `Shareholders` in your case. You have to remake your model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    meeting_id = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=CASCADE)
    shareholder_IC = models.ForeignKey(Shareholders_Meeting, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='questions')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.meeting_id)
```

Then, in your `views.py` you need to use the correct attribute name in the `Question` model, which is `shareholders_IC`:

```
def getMessages(request, meeting_id):  # <- Shouldn't the first param be request?
    meeting = Meeting.objects.get(meeting_ID=meeting_id)
    # No need to use meeting.meeting_ID here, you can use the meeting instance
    questions = Question.objects.filter(meeting_id=meeting)
    for i in questions:
        print(i.shareholder_IC)  # <- No .all(), a question has only one shareholder
    
    return JsonResponse({"questions":list(questions.values())})
```

However, to achieve what you want, you should either use Django REST Framework, or serialize yourself the different instances that you'll get:

```
def getMessages(request, meeting_id):
    meeting = Meeting.objects.get(meeting_ID=meeting_id)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(meeting_id=meeting)
    questions_list = []
    for i in questions:
        questions_list.append(
            {
                "question_ID": i.question_ID,
                "question": i.question,
                "shareholder_IC_id": i.shareholder_IC.shareholder_IC,
                ...
            }
        )
    
    return JsonResponse(questions_list)
```

I would recommend two main things:

1. Learn about relationships in Django and how to represent them in your models. You shouldn't have an attribute `meeting_id`, for example, in your `Question`. Although internally the id is indeed being used to query the `Meeting`, the attribute has a relationship to the model, not to the ID.
2. Use DRF. It will really help you a lot.

Comment: Instead of iteration i suggest you to use method `values()` - [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)

Comment: Although that is indeed better and it's what I would use, I feel like OP is a beginner at Django and it might be better to keep it simple for now.

Answer (score 0):

You must use backward relations

```
questions = Question.shareholder_ic.filter(meeting_id=meeting.meeting_ID)
```

Do not touch it on the object

For other settings, create the required query set in manager